# Can anyone can tell how to make this layout in flutter as i am new in flutter i am stuck in this

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image]

The marked thing in the picture can someone can tell how to make this type of card in a flutter. as i am new in flutter

Comment: Check this out https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for your UI

```
Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 7,
                              offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'Hello,',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Test User',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                                      height: 40,
                                      width: 3,
                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                    ),
                                    TextButton.icon(
                                      style: ButtonStyle(
                                        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orange),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.rice_bowl),
                                      label: Text('Show Card'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Text(
                                'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create widgets, start thinking of it step by step,

so in the widget you are talking about, the parent widget will be the white container, with shadow around its border to create the floating behavior.

[image]

inside this container you need the basic column in order to have the widgets over each other.

this column will have two widgets which are the upper body and lower text as shown here

[image]

now the lower one is just text so it does not need any extra work.

the upper body there is a column to the left and two widgets on the right so we need a Row for this, this row will have the three widgets shown here

[image]

this row will contain :-

the blue widget which is a column with two texts

the green which is a line you can use container widget for this

the yellow widget is also a Row that contain an Icon widget and a text widget

Since you are new to flutter I advise you to try to create the code by yourself with keeping these steps in mind, you can post the code here if you got stuck and we will help you.

Comment: Hello can i ask you a question

Comment: Hi, its properly too late now, but you can ask if you still facing a problem